# Python 3.8 Tk Tkinter ttk.Treeview Insert does not populate and display in frame

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am not a rookie, but am not vastly experienced either. I am using PyCharm and python 3.8. I am trying to cobble together a quick & dirty utility for our customers to validate input files to production application. I have heard of python Tk so I found some code on the web, borrowed it, and modified for my purposes. The code sample is amateurish, but the data does not display in the ttk.TreeView object. If you stop the PyCharm debugger at the end of the populate_data function, the code segment

```
for child in tree.get_children():
    print(tree.item(child)["values"])
```

in the PyCharm evaluator shows the TreeView object has children.

I do not understand why the TreeView children are not displayed correctly.  Here is my UGLY code example. Functions are provided just to make the code executable.
**Thanks in advance.**

The parts where the issue exists is in the **main()** and **populate_data** functions.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import simpledialog

from tkinter import *
import sys
import os

# designate default test environment
global execution_env
global db_server
execution_env = "Integration"
db_server = "autv-bitest01"

global header_list
header_list = ["Entity HCC ID", "Entity Type", "Issue Code", "OE Flag", "Effective Date",
               "Override", "Requestor", "Date Dropped", "Note"]
global base_window
base_window = None
global tree_frame
tree_frame = None
global tree
tree = None
global btn_env_text
btn_env_text = None
global btn_env
btn_env = None


global test_data
test_data = [
    ["A", "val2", "val3", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["B", "asd2", "asd3", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["C", "bbb3", "bbb4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["D", "ccc3", "ccc4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["E", "ddd3", "ddd4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["F", "Abb3", "Abb4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["G", "Bcc3", "Bcc4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["H", "Cdd3", "Cdd4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["I", "Dbb3", "Dbb4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["J", "Ecc3", "Ecc4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
    ["L", "eee3", "eee4", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x3"]
]


def main():
    """
    MAIN code
    :return: NA
    """
    # MAIN CODE -- function main -- MAIN CODE
    global base_window
    global tree_frame
    global tree
    global btn_env
    global btn_env_text
    global execution_env
    global db_server

    if (len(db_server) == 0) and (len(execution_env) == 0):
        info_title = "OE Mass Order GUI"
        msg = "Execution environment is required"
        messagebox.showinfo(info_title, msg)
        sys.exit()

    base_window = Tk()
    base_window.geometry("1400x500")
    base_window.option_add('*background', 'yellow')
    base_window.title("OE Mass Order GUI")

    # label_text = StringVar()
    # label_text.set("ENVIRONMENT: " + execution_env + "   (" + db_server + ")")
    # label = Label(base_window, textvariable=label_text, relief=RAISED)
    # label.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=TOP)

    btn_env_text = StringVar()
    btn_env_text = "Set environment: " + execution_env + "   (" + db_server + ")"
    btn_env = Button(base_window, text=btn_env_text, command=perform_choose, height=2)
    btn_env.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=TOP)

    tree_frame = Frame(base_window)
    tree_frame.pack(pady=20)

    tree = ttk.Treeview(base_window, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), height=10, show="headings")

    tree.heading(1, text="Entity HCC ID")
    tree.heading(2, text="Entity Type")
    tree.heading(3, text="Issue Code")
    tree.heading(4, text="OE Flag")
    tree.heading(5, text="Effective Date")
    tree.heading(6, text="Override")
    tree.heading(7, text="Requestor")
    tree.heading(8, text="Date Dropped")
    tree.heading(9, text="Note")

    tree.column(1, width=150)
    tree.column(2, width=150)
    tree.column(3, width=150)
    tree.column(4, width=150)
    tree.column(5, width=150)
    tree.column(6, width=150)
    tree.column(7, width=150)
    tree.column(8, width=150)
    tree.column(8, width=150)

    y_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(base_window, orient=VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
    y_scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scroll.set)

    # wrap it up by loading data frame contents with test_data
    populate_data(test_data)   # populate tree data from test_data list

    btn_frame = Frame(base_window)

    btn_quit = Button(btn_frame, text="Quit", height=2, command=base_window.destroy)
    btn_quit.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

    btn_submit = Button(btn_frame, height=2, text="Submit")
    btn_submit["command"] = perform_submit
    btn_submit.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

    btn_append = Button(btn_frame, height=2, text="Append")
    btn_append["command"] = perform_append
    btn_append.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

    btn_import = Button(btn_frame, height=2, text="Import")
    btn_import["command"] = perform_import
    btn_import.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

    btn_clear = Button(btn_frame, height=2, text="Clear")
    btn_clear["command"] = perform_clear
    btn_clear.pack(padx=10, pady=20, side=LEFT)

    btn_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    base_window.mainloop()

    return


def populate_data(data_to_insert, debug_print=False):
    global tree

    my_data = data_to_insert
    if len(data_to_insert) > 0:
        for val in my_data:
            tree.insert(parent='', index='end',
                        values=(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6], val[7], val[8])
                        )

    # DEBUG BLOCK TO VIEW CONTENT OF treeview FRAME
    if debug_print:
        print("\n==========================")
        for child in tree.get_children():
            print(tree.item(child)["values"])
    return


def perform_choose():
    return


def perform_import():
    return


def perform_clear():
    return


def perform_append():
    return


def perform_submit():
    return


# --- THE REAL MAIN CODE ---
if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()

    # terminate
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: This is just far too much code. Stackoverflow isn't designed to be a free debugging service. Please try to condense the code down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `tree.pack()` or `tree.grid()`, so `tree` will not be shown.  Also I think that `tree` and `y_scroll` should be children of `tree_frame`, not `base_window`.

```py
...
# used tree_frame as parent instead of base_window
tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), height=15, show="headings")
tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)
...
# used tree_frame as parent instead of base_window
y_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
y_scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
...
```

Comment: THANK YOU, acw1668! That was the answer key I needed, but couldn't find. Here is my final code version.

Comment: @user1313358 You should put your changes in your question or post them as another answer.